# How to start OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: server, openvpn, systemd

The `systemd` unit `openvpn.service` uses `/bin/true` for `ExecStart` and `ExecReload` directives. Someone made the mistake to add the comment

```
# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.
```

instead of

```
# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.
# [Explanation how to start the server]
```

`sudo netstat -tupln | grep 1194` reveals that OpenVPN isn't running (`port` in `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` is 1194).

The `openvpn@.service` unit is the `OpenVPN connection to %i` which won't start the server.

Comment: This topic on U&L seems similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/using-openvpn-with-systemd, maybe it helps.